# Android Passing a list of objects from activity to tabs fragmets

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having a problem here
i have activity with tablayout viewpager get objects from database and pass them by bundle to the tabs fragment
the problem is bundle getting null in the tab fragment

here is the Activity

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Categorys extends DrawerActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    String url,result;

    //This is our tablayout
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    //This is our viewPager
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    DBhelper db;
    Bundle bundle;

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorys);
        //Adding toolbar to the activity
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        set();

        db = new DBhelper(Categorys.this);
        db.open();
        List<ProductObj> productslistfromDB = db.getAllProductsUp();
        db.close();

    ProductObj product = productslistfromDB.get(0);
    String namee = product.getName();
    String details = product.getDetails();
    String category = product.getcategory();
    String ownerr = product.getOwner();
    String weight = product.getWeight();
    String size = product.getSize();
    String price = product.getPrice();
    String imageurl = product.getimageurl();
    String owner_address = product.getOwner_address();
    String owner_phone = product.getOwner_phone();
    String UID = product.getUID();

    productpojo productpoj = new productpojo();
    productpoj.setName(namee);
    productpoj.setDetails(details);
    productpoj.setcategory(category);
    productpoj.setOwner(ownerr);
    productpoj.setWeight(weight);
    productpoj.setSize(size);
    productpoj.setPrice(price);
    productpoj.setimageurl(imageurl);
    productpoj.setOwner_address(owner_address);
    productpoj.setOwner_phone(owner_phone);
    productpoj.setUID(UID);

    ArrayList<productpojo> productlisttosend = new ArrayList<>();
    productlisttosend.add(productpoj);

    Tab1 fragmentGet1 = new Tab1();
    Tab2 fragmentGet2 = new Tab2();
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("arraylist", productlisttosend);
    fragmentGet1.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentGet2.setArguments(bundle);

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_clothes));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_electrical));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_hammer));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_cars));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_interior_accesories));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_buid));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

    }




@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
{
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
}
```

and here is the first fragment Tab1

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by toshiba c660-12T on 16/08/2016.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    GridView gv;
    int[] clicknums;
    ArrayList<productpojo> productarraylist = null;
    Bundle bundle;


    //Overriden method onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

         bundle=this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            productarraylist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");
        }
        go();

        return view;
    }



    public void go(){
    productpojo propoj; = productarraylist.get(0);
    String namee = propoj.getName();
    String details = propoj.getDetails();
    String category = propoj.getcategory();
    String ownerr = propoj.getOwner();
    String weight = propoj.getWeight();
    String size = propoj.getSize();
    String price = propoj.getPrice();
    String imageurl = propoj.getimageurl();
    String owner_address = propoj.getOwner_address();
    String owner_phone = propoj.getOwner_phone();
    String UID = propoj.getUID();

    ProductObj product = new ProductObj();
    product.setName(namee);
    product.setDetails(details);
    product.setcategory(category);
    product.setOwner(ownerr);
    product.setWeight(weight);
    product.setSize(size);
    product.setPrice(price);
    product.setimageurl(imageurl);
    product.setOwner_address(owner_address);
    product.setOwner_phone(owner_phone);
    product.setUID(UID);

    final ArrayList<ProductObj> productlist = new ArrayList<>();
    productlist.add(product);

    gv = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid);
    clicknums = new int[productlist.size()];
    gv.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(), productlist));
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

    int clicknum;
    clicknums[position] = clicknums[position] + 1;
    clicknum = clicknums[position];
    String image = productlist.get(position).imageurl;
    String text = productlist.get(position).name;
    String owenr = productlist.get(position).owner;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Product.class);
    intent.putExtra("numofclick", clicknum);
    intent.putExtra("title", text);
    intent.putExtra("owner", owenr);
    intent.putExtra("image", image);

    //Start details activity
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
    }
```

and here is the second fragment Tab2

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by toshiba c660-12T on 16/08/2016.
 */
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

    GridView gv;
    int[] clicknums;
    ArrayList<productpojo> productarraylist = null;
    Bundle bundle;


    //Overriden method onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

        bundle=this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            productarraylist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("arraylist");
        }
        go();

        return view;
    }



    public void go(){
    productpojo propoj; = productarraylist.get(0);
    String namee = propoj.getName();
    String details = propoj.getDetails();
    String category = propoj.getcategory();
    String ownerr = propoj.getOwner();
    String weight = propoj.getWeight();
    String size = propoj.getSize();
    String price = propoj.getPrice();
    String imageurl = propoj.getimageurl();
    String owner_address = propoj.getOwner_address();
    String owner_phone = propoj.getOwner_phone();
    String UID = propoj.getUID();

    ProductObj product = new ProductObj();
    product.setName(namee);
    product.setDetails(details);
    product.setcategory(category);
    product.setOwner(ownerr);
    product.setWeight(weight);
    product.setSize(size);
    product.setPrice(price);
    product.setimageurl(imageurl);
    product.setOwner_address(owner_address);
    product.setOwner_phone(owner_phone);
    product.setUID(UID);

    final ArrayList<ProductObj> productlist = new ArrayList<>();
    productlist.add(product);

    gv = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid);
    clicknums = new int[productlist.size()];
    gv.setAdapter(new CustomGrid(getActivity(), productlist));
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

    int clicknum;
    clicknums[position] = clicknums[position] + 1;
    clicknum = clicknums[position];
    String image = productlist.get(position).imageurl;
    String text = productlist.get(position).name;
    String owenr = productlist.get(position).owner;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Product.class);
    intent.putExtra("numofclick", clicknum);
    intent.putExtra("title", text);
    intent.putExtra("owner", owenr);
    intent.putExtra("image", image);

    //Start details activity
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    });
    }
```

pager class

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by toshiba c660-12T on 16/08/2016.
 */

//Extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    //integer to count number of tabs
    int tabCount;

    //Constructor to the class
    public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        //Initializing tab count
        this.tabCount= tabCount;
    }

    //Overriding method getItem
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    //Overriden method getCount to get the number of tabs
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: is your productpojo parceleable?

Comment: also fragmentGet2 and fragmentGet1 don't interact with your pager at all. You created two fragments, added a bundle to then and you're not using them in any other way.

Comment: @Olayinka yes productpojo is parceleable.. and i didn't get what you said about fragmentGet2 and fragmentGet1

Comment: I meant that your pager adapter isn't interacting with the fragment at all. Look at https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager Unless there is some logic in the  Pager class that you didn't add in the question

Comment: i have class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter but i did't added it @Olayinka

Comment: Add your pager class to the question

Comment: i added the pager class @Olayinka

Answer (score 2):

Need to call `getArguments()` in `onCreateView` to get Bundle which is send using `setArguments` :

```
bundle=this.getArguments();
```

Comment: i did what you said.. still bundle getting null